Como hacer esta resta con JavaScript? No puedo restar a los 3500 los 250 usados
<script type="text/javascript">

    const d = document,
          c = console,
        btn = d.getElementById("btn")

    let minaMetalNivel = d.querySelector(".mina_metal-nivel"),
    produccionHora = d.querySelector(".produccion_hora")

    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      let metalUnidades = d.getElementById("metal_unidades"),
      cristalUnidades = d.getElementById("cristal_unidades"),
      existenciaMetal = d.querySelector(".existencia_metal"),
      valorMetal = metalUnidades.value,
      valorCristal = cristalUnidades.value,
      metalExistente = existenciaMetal.value
      c.log(valorMetal)
      c.log(valorCristal)
  
    if(valorMetal === "250" && valorCristal === "85") {
    minaMetalNivel.textContent = 2
    produccionHora.textContent = 100 
    valorMetal.textContent = valorMetal * 2
    
    c.log(metalExistente)
    metalExistente - valorMetal
     } else {
      alert("faltan recursos")
    }
    })
</script>


No se entiende tu pregunta.

Mina de metal de nivel 
    1
Metal: 
 Produccion por hora 25
Metal necesario 250 unidades

Cristal necesario 85 unidades

Construir
Es que no se como funciona esta página.

Quiero restar a los 3500 de metal lo los 250 que uso y no encuentro como. Tampoco veo como subir todo el código de una vez

Tengo 3500 de metal y en el if else uso 250, pero no puedo lograr que al final esos 250 sean restados a los 3500

Estas haciendo la resta sin asignar el resultado a ninguna variable.

La variable metalExistente debería estar en 3500 y probé así: metalExistente = metalExistente - valorMetal y tampoco me da

En el útlimo fragmento tienes un IF que es donde realizas la resta.
if(valorMetal === "250" && valorCristal === "85") {
    minaMetalNivel.textContent = 2
    produccionHora.textContent = 100 
    valorMetal.textContent = valorMetal * 2

    c.log(metalExistente)
    metalExistente - valorMetal; //Acá realizas la resta
} else {
    alert("Faltan recursos");
}

Pero como ves, no estás asignando el resultado a ningun lado.
La pregunta es entonces, donde quieres guardar el resultado ?
Puedes:
1.- Actualizar el valor de metalExistente
metalExistente -= valorMetal; //Opcion1
// o para que sea entendible mas simple
metalExistente = metalExistente - valorMetal; //Opcion2

2.- Guardar el resultado en una nueva variable
let metalRestante = metalExistente - valorMetal;

Yo he de suponer que la primera opcion es la que buscas, pero luego no se que quieres hacer con el valor. Asi que, puedes imprimirlo.
c.log("Resultado: " + mi_variable);


Para agregar a un input el valor, puedes hacer:
document.querySelector('.existencia_metal').value = metalExistente;


Hola, ahora puedo hacer la resta y ese resultado debería aparecer aquí: Metal: , fuera de eso también he logrado imprimirlo en consola (antes de tu ayuda siempre imprimía el valor original de 3500)

Al final agregué como hacerlo para actualizar el input.
